# How to prevent ElasticBeanstalk removing instances whilst scaling up

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I struggled to find a solution to my problem so I'd like to throw this one out there for some suggestions.

I'm using ElasticBeanstalk which has a minimum of four instances. Now when the environment is required to scale up, it will add an instance and begin its process to deploy the application, which can take up to 10 minutes.

For example, my environment proceeds to do this and within this time period, technically we are at 5 (4 are stable, 1 is deploying and failing health checks) but it can potentially remove a healthy instance leaving me with 3 healthy instances rather than the required minimum of 4.

How can I prevent this? Is there a way for ElasticBeanstalk to only remove instances when there are 4 *healthy* instances?

My only solution right now is to lower the average CPU scaling triggers down, to ensure it doesn't hit it. The breach period I could increase, but this goes for scaling up as well as scaling down. Would be nice if these were separate.

Suggestions or questions much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: ```but it can potentially remove a healthy instance leaving me with 3 healthy instances rather than the required minimum of 4.``` what do you mean by he can remove a healthy instance ? During scale up activity beanstalk won't remove any instances

Comment: Hey, yeah it seemed odd to me. However, I noticed that when it was scaling up it had included the instance into the health measurements, measuring on CPU % the extra instance drastically brought it down below the scale down because it wasn't accepting traffic. So the environment thought overall the CPU crisis is over and pulls out the oldest instance in the group.. leaving me 3 instances accepting traffic and 1 that is still spinning up. Hope that helps?